# what is the part of '0' mean about 3 part ration such as the Y Cb Cr :4:2:0?

Tags: video-streaming

In some digital video terminology articles about the 3 part ratio of YCbCr. There is some definition of that below:

> "- a:x:y which defines the chroma resolution in relation to an ax2
>   block of a is the horizontal sampling reference (usually 4), x is the number of chroma samples in the first row of a pixel (horizontal resolution in
>   relation to a), and y is the number of changes of chroma samples
>   between the first and seconds rows of a pixel."

I couldn't totally understand what is the meaning of y part which indicates the changes of chroma samples, what that means? Hopefully get the response from someone has the good basics of digital videos. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's best to see it. The notation used here is `J:a:b`.

[image: Chroma Subsampling]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)